# On the picture of Schur limit of the superconformal index

Tags: conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, superconformality

My goal is to understand qualitatively (hopefully quantitatively in future) the existence of the relationship of the Schur limit of the superconformal index given by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(q)=\mathrm{Tr} \left[ (-1)^F q^{\Delta-\frac
{1}{2}R} \right]
\end{align}
on the chiral algebras of four four dimensional $\mathcal{N}=2$ superconformal field theories [1].

In particular, I know that this is related to the cohomology being equivalently defined by different supercharges, however, I am having difficult time understanding the background motivation of the relationship.

Would it be possible to gain some insight on how one should try to picture it?

$$$$
[1] C. Beem, M. Lemos, P. Liendo, W. Peelaers, L. Rastelli and B. C. van Rees, "Infinite Chiral Symmetry in Four Dimensions," Commun. Math. Phys. 336 (2015) no.3, 1359-1433 doi:10.1007/s00220-014-2272-x [arXiv:1312.5344 [hep-th]].